# Repetition of final line when computing sum?

Tags: c

I'm taking my first programming class ever this year and I'm slight confused on this. I'm trying to learn the fopen and fclose functions currently.

My code is

```
int main(void)
{
        FILE *input; /* Pointer to the input file */
        double values;
        double sum;

input = fopen("data.dat", "r"); /* Prepare file for input */

sum = 0;
while (!feof(input))
{       fscanf(input, "%lf", &values);
    sum = sum + values;
}

printf("The sum of the values is %f\n", sum);

fclose(input);
return 0;
}
```

When I compile this to get the sum, the last value of the data.dat file is counted for twice.
I was wondering how I could fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't what this should be tagged, but R is a statistical programming language that you are definitely not using.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant to have it tagged as C.

Comment: Because `while(!feof)` is always wrong.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof even in the docs they do not use feof in a loop

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `while(!feof(...))` because it's always wrong. Why?

It will, as you found out, loop one more time than you expect. That happens because the semantics of `feof()` are not what you think: that is, they are **not** to check if the *next* read will reach the end of file. Instead, `feof` allows you distinguish between a read error and the end of the file after you get a zero from a `read` (or some other similar call).

The solution to your problem is easy: use the functions you call properly. `fscanf` returns a value - you should find out what that value is and, more importantly, what it means.